# python converting set to list strange list behavior

Tags: python

I must be missing something because this is strange...

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a1 = ['b', 'a']
foo = list( set(a) - set(a1))
```

** returning **

```
foo == ['c']
type(foo) == <type 'list'>
foo[0] == 'c'
```

** now the strange part **

```
foo = foo.insert(0, 'z')
foo == None
```

why do list operations like insert, and append cause foo to be None??

the following accomplishes what my top example attempts to but seems ridiculous.

```
import itertools

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a1 = ['b', 'a']

foo = list(set(a) - set(a1))
q = [['z']]
q.append(foo)
q = [i for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(q)]
q == ['z', 'c']
```

any insight would be appreciated. 
thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, `foo==None` returns `False`.

Comment: did you type `foo = foo.insert(0, 'z')` by accident? that would cause it to be None.

Comment: Corley Brigman is correct. I was essentially assigning my list variable the return value of .insert(), which as NPE pointed out is in fact None..

Comment: I edited my question to reflect Corley Brigman's comment. Changing foo.insert(0, 'z') to foo = foo.insert(0, 'z'). Thanks everyone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`foo.insert()` *returns* `None`, but does change `foo` in the way you'd expect:

```
>>> foo = ['c']
>>> foo.insert(0, 'z')
>>> foo
['z', 'c']
```

If you wish to assign the result to a different variable, here is one way to do it:

```
>>> foo = ['c']
>>> bar = ['z'] + foo
>>> bar
['z', 'c']
```

Comment: +1, are you perhaps doing `print foo.insert(0, 'z')`?

Comment: the foo.inster(0, 'z') was being used as the return statement in a function. So it was literally ... return foo.insert(0, 'z'). Which explains why I was getting None.. And proves how painfully oblivious I can be sometimes.. Thank you for pointing this out to me.